# Does this iframe buster script look safe?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

We're being asked to host a number of iframe buster scripts on our site - they allow ads which are served from external domains into iframes to expand outside of them into the host page. Our hosting provider's warned us to watch out for security holes in these scripts. Specifically, they say some of them create cross-site scripting holes by allowing a piece of Javascript to be loaded into our site from any URL.

To implement the script, you host an HTML page on your site. I'm looking at an example from the ad provider Atlas. In this case the URL is like http://domain.com/atlas/atlas_rm.htm. That page contains a script tag with src at an external URL, and here's the JS it includes:

```
var ARMIfbLib = function () {

    function documentWrite(htmlString) {
        document.write(htmlString);
    }

    function writeIframeBustingScript() {
        var imgSrvPath = getTlDirectoryFromQueryString(getParameterString());
        if (imgSrvPath != "") {
            var scriptURL = imgSrvPath + getScriptFileName();
            ARMIfbLib.DocumentWrite("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='" + scriptURL + "'></scr" + "ipt>");
        }
    }

    return {
        WriteIframeBustingScript: writeIframeBustingScript,
        DocumentWrite: documentWrite
    }

}();

function getValueFromDelimitedString(paramKey, delimiter, queryString) {
    if (paramKey == "imgSrv")
        return getValueFromProperties();

    var re = new RegExp(paramKey + "=" + "(.*?)" + "(" + delimiter + "|$)");
    var matchArray = queryString.match(re);
    if (matchArray == null)
        return "";
    else
        return matchArray[1];
}

function getValueFromProperties() {
    var iframename = unescape(self.name);
    if (iframename.indexOf("<form") >= 0) {
        var params = iframename.split("<input ");
        for (var i = 1; i < params.length; i++) {
            var parts = params[i].split(" ");
            for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
                var param = parts[j].split("=");
                if (param[0].indexOf("name") >= 0 && param[1].indexOf("TL_files_path") >= 0) {
                    param = parts[j + 1].split("=");
                    if (param[0].indexOf("value") >= 0) {
                        var value = param[1].substr(1, param[1].indexOf(">"));
                        value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/"));
                        value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        return unescape(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (iframename.indexOf("adparamdelim") >= 0) {
        var params = iframename.split("adparamdelim");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var param = params[i].split("=");
            if (param[0].indexOf("TL_files_path") >= 0) {
                var value = param[1];
                value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/"));
                value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (/^\{.*\}$/.test(iframename)) {
        try {
            eval('var results = ' + iframename);
            var value = results.TL_files_path;
            value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/"));
            value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            return value;
        } catch (e) {
            return "";
        }
    } else {
        var params = iframename.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var param = params[i].split("=");
            if (param[0].indexOf("TL_files_path") >= 0) {
                var value = unescape(param[1]);
                value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/"));
                value = value.substr(value, value.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function getTlDirectoryFromQueryString(sLocation) {
    var queryVar = getValueFromDelimitedString("imgSrv", "a4edelim", sLocation);
    var temp = queryVar.substr(0, queryVar.lastIndexOf("/"));
    var tlDir = temp.substr(0, temp.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return tlDir;
}

function getDocumentQueryString() {
    return window.location.search;
}

function getIframeParameterString() {
    var ret = "";
    var qs = getDocumentQueryString();
    if (qs.length > 0)
        ret = qs.substring(1);
    return ret;
}

function getScriptParameterString() {
    var ret = "";
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var scriptSrc = scripts[i].src;
        if (scriptSrc.toLowerCase().indexOf("newiframescript") != -1 && scriptSrc.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            ret = scriptSrc.substr(scriptSrc.indexOf("?") + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

function getParameterString() {
    var qs = getIframeParameterString();
    if (qs.length > 0 && qs.indexOf("a4edelim") > 0)
        return qs;
    return getScriptParameterString();
}

function getScriptFileName() {
    var armdelim = ",";
    var fileName = "ifb.0";
    var queryString = getParameterString();
    var parmValue = "";
    if (queryString.length > 0) {
        parmValue = getValueFromDelimitedString("armver", "a4edelim", queryString);
    }
    if (parmValue.length > 0) {
        var fileNames = parmValue.split(armdelim);
        for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
            if (fileNames[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("ifb") != -1) {
                fileName = fileNames[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return fileName + ".js";
}

if (typeof(armTestMode) == "undefined") {
    ARMIfbLib.WriteIframeBustingScript();
}
```

I've spent a couple of hours studying this to try and work out what it's doing, but I've got bogged down in the different function calls. It seems to be grabbing a query string parameter or else a value from the name of an iframe, presumably the iframe the contains the ad.

Can anyone understand what this JS is doing? Does it look fairly safe from a XSS point of view?

=========================================

EDIT

In case useful to anybody else, we mentioned this concern to the providers, and their response was:

1. The iframe buster page will only work if it is in an iframe
2. The code in the ftlocal.html file will only work if the domain of the iframe is already the same as the domain of the parent page – So any code would already have access to the parent page anyway

Comment: If you're including a JavaScirpt reference from an external domain, your page is at the whim of the script. You're effectively allowing your page to trust the external domain, so the script could manipulate any of your content via the DOM.

Comment: Thanks SilverlightFox, I understand you have to trust the provider - I'm more concerned about malicious third parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the JS script creates a dynamically generated script tag in your page.

`ARMIfbLib.DocumentWrite("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='" + scriptURL + "'></scr" + "ipt>");`

If you dig into where `scriptURL` comes from, it appears to be a parameter passed to `window.location.search` (the query string).

From what I can see this effectively allows any script to be passed to your page on the query string rendering it vulnerable to DOM XSS, unless it is effectively secured to allow the domain to be set by the frame name in your page. I'd do some testing using your own domains and passing the query string variables that are searched for (the string literals in the JS).

Comment: Thanks SilverlightFox, that confirms the impression I got about this script.